# Is this quote/poem by Mahmoud Darwish? "if they ask you about Gaza.."

Tags: quotes, palestine, gaza

A [quote](https://twitter.com/ZeeshanJaanam/status/1720163145828720914) about Gaza has become a meme on social media:

> And if they ask you about Gaza, tell them that it has a martyr, a martyr helps him, a martyr takes pictures of him, a martyr bids him farewell, and a martyr prays over him.
>
> *"Mahmoud Darwish"*

I saw the same quote/poem elsewhere, but there it was translated as "Palestine" instead of "Gaza".

e.g. [this photo description](https://www.flickr.com/photos/alisdare/52082106404/):

> And if they ask you about Palestine, tell them:
> In it there is a martyr,
> nursed by a martyr,
> photographed by a martyr,
> sent off by a martyr,
> and prayed for by a martyr"
>
> (Mahmoud Darwish)

Is this quote/poem by [Mahmoud Darwish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahmoud_Darwish)?

"Google book" and Google offers was hopeless.

Comment: You'd probably have search in Arabic for anything conclusive.

Comment: @Fizz My language is not Arabic, but I also searched in Arabic and none of the results mentioned a reference.

Answer (score 9):

Documentarily speaking? No, this quote was never mentioned in his complete works (not at least in my Arab Institute for Research & Publishing edition) or any other document (I've surfed Google Books with the original Arabic version).

However, it might be true that it belongs to him but it just was not documented as it's a very common quote and it's widely used in Arabic media and conferences (see for example [here](https://www.aljazeeramubasher.net/news/miscellaneous/2018/8/9/%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%B0%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%89-%D8%B1%D8%AD%D9%8A%D9%84%D9%87-%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%8A%D8%B4-%D9%8A%D8%B5%D9%85%D8%AA-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A3%D8%AC%D9%84) from aljazeera, [arabicpost.net [ex HuffPost Arabi]](https://arabicpost.net/%D8%AB%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%A9/2023/10/30/%D8%B4%D8%B9%D8%B1-%D8%B9%D9%86-%D8%BA%D8%B2%D8%A9/) both reference it to Mahmoud Darwish).

Here's the Arabic version of the quote, it uses "Gaza" instead of Palestine, the version with "Palestine" does not exist at all in Arabic:

> إن سألوك عن غزة، قل لهم: بها شهيد، يُسعفه شهيد، ويُصوره شهيد، ويودّعه شهيد ويصلي عليه شهيد

Note that Darwish had many poems about Gaza and the Palestinian Resistance, if you are questioning the likelihood of him saying such a thing, then it's likely.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Are you saying that because you've read/searched [all of his books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahmoud_Darwish#Published_works) or just because you couldn't find it using search engines? Do you have [all his books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahmoud_Darwish#Published_works) in your institution?

Comment: Yes, "complete works" publication consists of all of his works, and this quote does not exist there, from my search.

Comment: So +1. You say "the version with "Palestine" does not exist at all in Arabic". [See this page.](https://www.alaraby.co.uk/%D9%81%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%88%D9%86-%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%B5%D8%B1-%D8%A2%D8%AA%D9%8D) But it can be a translation from English to Arabic.

Comment: This page says that the artist "Mahmoud El-Bezzawy posted" on his personal profile [the quote]. My guess is the artist got the wrong quote and Alaraby just reposted it like that.

Comment: What is the date of the oldest web page you could find that contains this quote? The Al Jazeera link is from 2018.

Comment: Oldest form I could find is from 2013 using Google search. I found a Facebook post from 2011 with the same quote but with Egypt instead of Gaza (relating to the 2011 Egyptian revolution) [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo?fbid=298255000195058&set=a.180522695301623).. This does not necessarily indicate anything, Arabic Web did not start to propagate like that until recently. I guess other quotes form Nizar Qabbani for example would seem as much as recent.